# Why can't I set the height of my table data rows, but can set the height of my table headers?

Tags: html, css

I've tried all the solutions I can find but the closest I can get to a uniform row height is editing the height of my table headers, the table data rows won't change their height, no matter what I change.

My HTML:

```
<div class="fields">
            <table>
                <tr>                                   
                    <th>Year</th>
                    <th id="clickable" onclick="openPopup('f2')">Yield/Year</th>
                    <th id="clickable" onclick="openPopup('f3')">Yield/Year*3</th>
                    <th id="clickable" onclick="openPopup('f4')">Yield/Year*3*4</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>387.58</td>
                    <td>1162.74</td>
                    <td>4650.96</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
</div>
```

My CSS:

```
.fields table {
    width: auto;
    table-layout: fixed;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.fields td {
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    color: #213B54;
    font-size: 16px;
    border-right: 2px solid #213B54;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #213B54;
    text-align: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.fields th {
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    border-right: 2px solid #213B54;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #213B54;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    padding-left: 2px;
    padding-right: 2px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #9bdcdf;
    color: #067A9F;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    width: 75px;
    height: 10px;
}
```

Comment: in your CSS you used class(.fields) to style table but in HTML you not used class? please check and clear this

Comment: Div got cut off, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: I'm still trying to understand why changing the height of the rows for table data prevents me from changing the height of the table headers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you should have to do is write a style that targets `tr`, optionally with classes to differentiate between your header and data rows.

EDIT: By the way, I just noticed that you have the same ID on multiple elements. IDs should uniquely identify a single element. To apply styles to multiple elements, you should use classes.

```css
table {
  width: auto;
  table-layout: fixed;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

td {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #213B54;
  font-size: 16px;
  border-right: 2px solid #213B54;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #213B54;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

th {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  border-right: 2px solid #213B54;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #213B54;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  padding-left: 2px;
  padding-right: 2px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #9bdcdf;
  color: #067A9F;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  width: 75px;
  height: 10px;
}

tr.table-header {
  height: 50px;
}

tr.table-data {
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr class="table-header">
    <th>Year</th>
    <th id="clickable" onclick="openPopup('f2')">Yield/Year</th>
    <th id="clickable" onclick="openPopup('f3')">Yield/Year*3</th>
    <th id="clickable" onclick="openPopup('f4')">Yield/Year*3*4</th>
  </tr>
  <tr class="table-data">
    <td>1</td>
    <td>387.58</td>
    <td>1162.74</td>
    <td>4650.96</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: For some reason when I do this, even if I use ID to select only the rows with my table data in, it will ignore the height I've set for my table headers. Without setting the row height, it lets the headers be a different height.

Comment: I updated the snippet to address that. I added a `table-header` class to the header row, and a `table-data` class to the data row

Comment: Also, when I change the amount of data in the table, the row height changes despite having a fixed table layout, and having had the row height set?

Comment: That was my first thought, but despite selecting them separately they both seem to get ignored beyond a certain point - say trying to set them both as 20px and with 10 rows of data in the table.

Comment: You can't set the height of the row to be less than the line height of the text in the row. If I were to edit that snippet so that `.table-data` has a height of 20px, it would look exactly the same as if `.table-data` had a height of 10px

Comment: the HTML and CSS you shared here, is this structure or CSS applied using javascript?

Comment: @ahmedmoeed the snippet is self-contained. There is no JavaScript other than the `onclick` attributes that OP included. And those are nonfunctional because the JavaScript wasn't included.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I was forgetting about line-height. One more thing, is it possible to set a consistent height? When I change the amount of rows in the table, it changes the row height, ignoring the height that was set. I think that's because the table is trying to fit to a specific height but I can't work out why as I haven't set its height anywhere, it should just use the height it needs for the rows.

Comment: Nevermind, I figured out the problem - the flex container .fields was using flex-direction row and forcing the table to expand to full height, effectively sizing the rows for it (hence the weird business with ignoring row height). Thanks for all your help.

Comment: Haha no worries. I was just typing up a response suggesting that it might be related to other styles that you didn't post here.